# IDTFT of delta sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

I am trying to compute

$$
\int_{-1/2}^{+1/2} \sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(\nu+n) \cdot e^{i\cdot2\pi\nu\cdot k} \,d\nu
$$

My stuck attempts: 
\begin{multline}
\int_{-1/2}^{+1/2} \sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(\nu+n) \cdot e^{i\cdot2\pi\nu\cdot k} \,d\nu= 
 \sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-1/2}^{+1/2}\delta(\nu+n) \cdot e^{i\cdot2\pi\nu\cdot k}  \,d\nu= 1
\end{multline}

Assuming that $n,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\int_{I} \delta(x-x_0) \cdot f(x) = f(x_0)$ if $x$ is interior point of $I$ and $0$ otherwise it seems that integral under the sum is zero always except $n = 0$ where it equals 1.

I feel that something is wrong with this, cause I feel that I should get some discrete sum function, not continuous one

Comment: Please tell us in what space you are trying to compute this.  Some space of Schwartz distributions?

Comment: @GEdgar I think if I ask my teacher ofdigital signal processing he would answer usual Hilbert space. What s the problem with the space?

Comment: $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(\nu +n)$ is a distribution, not a function, and it doesn't belong to some Hilbert space. As $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(\nu+n) f(\nu)d\nu =  f(-n)$ whenever $f$ is continuous at $\nu = -n$ then $\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \delta(\nu+n) e^{2i \pi \nu k} d\nu$ $ =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(\nu+n) e^{2i \pi \nu k}1_{\nu \in [-1/2,1/2]} d\nu =  e^{2i \pi (-n) k}1_{-n \in [-1/2,1/2]}=1_{-n \in [-1/2,1/2]}$ and hence yes the result is $\int_{-1/2}^{+1/2} \sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(\nu+n)  e^{2i\pi\nu k} d\nu = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty 1_{-n \in [-1/2,1/2]} = 1$

Comment: @reuns I knew that teacher of electronics doesn't know math well, he just gave delta function as $\delta (t) = +\infty , t = 0$ and $0$ otherwise and made some crazy even for me things. Actually, I agree with your statement, but the correct result should be $\sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} 1_{k=m}$

Comment: I wrote all the steps. If you have $1_{k = n}$ appearing it means you made some change of variable. You should think to $\delta(x)$ as the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ of $\frac{1_{|x| < \epsilon}}{2 \epsilon}$, which converges **in the distribution topology** (ie. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) f(x)dx \overset{def}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1_{|x| < \epsilon}}{2 \epsilon} f(x)dx$ converges for any nice enough function $f$)

Comment: @reuns it converges to the $f(0)$ for any nice enough function, isn't it? sorry, this subject assumes that we know nothing about topologies. sorry, i feel empty in this conversation...

Comment: A topology is just what you need to make sense to convergence and limits of sequences, here to $\delta(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1_{|x| < \epsilon}}{2 \epsilon}$ which converges in the distribution topology, but diverges in any function topology (for example in $L^2$)

Comment: @reuns I can't believe that some change in topology can change result from $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} 1_{n = 0}$ (assuming $n\in\mathbb{Z}$) to $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} 1_{n = k}$. initial expression converges to the same things, isn't it?!

Answer (score 0):

You are evidently being asked to determine the Fourier transform of the Dirac comb $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \delta_n$. (This is a tempered distribution so such computations can be legitimized...) You can already take the Fourier transform of $\delta_n$, which is a translate of $\delta_0$, whose Fourier transform is $1$. Fourier transform does not preserve translation (so you won't get $1_{x=n}$, but, rather, converts translation to multiplication by an exponential. So the Fourier transform of $\delta_n$ is $e^{2\pi inx}\cdot 1$ (depending on normalizations).

Thus, the Fourier transform of the Dirac comb is $\sum_n e^{2\pi inx}$.

This computation (which can be justified entirely...) gives another proof of the Poisson summation formula.

Yes, the fact that the Fourier transform of the infinite sum of translates of $\delta$ really is the infinite sum of the Fourier transforms depends on continuity properties in the topology of tempered distributions... but the natural heuristic does in fact give the true answer.

Comment: I am asked to determine IDTFT = Inverse Discrete Time Fourier Transform of $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(\nu + n)$